# removeZero() method when creating linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a LinkedList from scratch, in the form of a train. So I have a class called Domino which creates each node, and then I have the class Train, which includes the add, size, remove etc methods. My problem is:

- removeZeros() method: I cannot have any parameters, but I must delete all the nodes with zeros in them. What my program does instead is find all the zeros in the list, and delete all the nodes up until there are no more zeros. The zeros were added in a client class.

here is my Train class:

```
 public class Train{

 private Domino engine; 
 private Domino caboose;
 private int insertS;


public Train(){
    engine = null;
    caboose = engine;
}
/** WHERE IM HAVING TROUBLE
 * removeZero() - remove any Dominos from the train that have one or more zero spots
 * while maintaining the linked list structure.
 */

// method is now just getting the spot1 0 and printing that
public void removeZero(){
    Domino current = engine;
    Domino hold = caboose.next;

       while (current != hold) {

         if(current.spot1 == 0 ||current.spot2 == 0){

               current = current.next;
              engine = current;
               System.out.println("b " + engine);

            }else{

                current = current.next;


            }
          }
public String toString(){
    String ts = "{ empty }";
    if (engine == null) {
        return ts;
    } else {
        Domino hold = engine;
        ts = "{ ";
            while (hold != caboose) {
                ts += hold + ", ";
                hold = hold.next;
            }
        ts +=  hold + " }";
    }
    return ts;

}
/**
 *
 * add(spot1, spot2) - add a Domino to the end of the Train with the given spots
 */
public void add(int spot1, int spot2){
    if (engine == null) {
        engine = new Domino(spot1,spot2);
        caboose = engine;

    } else {
        caboose.next = new Domino(spot1, spot2, null,caboose);
        //tail.next.back = tail;
        caboose = caboose.next;
    }

}



}

/** 
 * reversePrint() - like toString, but provides a String that lists
 * all of the Dominos that are in the Train in reverse order
 */
public String reversePrint () {
    Domino hold = caboose;
    String reverse = "{ empty }";

    if (engine == null) {
        System.out.println(reverse);
    } else {
        reverse = "{ ";
            while (hold != engine){
                reverse += hold + ", ";
                hold = hold.back;
            }
        reverse += hold + " }";
    }
    return reverse;
}
/** 
 * size() - return the number of Dominos in the Train
 */
public int size(){
    int count = 0;
    Domino hold = engine;
    while(hold != null){
        hold = hold.next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
/** insert(spot1, spot2, next, back) - insert a Domino in the middle of
 * the Train where spot2 is the same as the spot1 of the next Domino and spot1
 * is the same as spot2 of the previous Domino.
 * (private)
 */
private void insert(int spot1,int spot2){
    if (!(insertS == search)) {
        Domino hold = engine;
        while (hold != caboose) {
            if (hold.spot1 == search) {
                Domino newDom = new Domino(spot1, spot2, null,caboose);     
                hold.next = newDom;               
                newDom.next.back = newDom;  
                hold = hold.next;               

            } else {
                hold = hold.next;               
            }   
        }       
        if (hold.spot2 == search) {
            add(spot1, spot2);                              
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(" ** Error Inserting these values will cause an infinite loop:");
        System.out.println(" * * * " + insertS + " and " + search + " * * *");
    }

}

/**
 * build() - scans through the Train creating links, using insert(spot1, spot2), between
 * existing Dominos where the second spot of the first Domino does not match the
 * first spot of the second domino, no param
 */

public void build(){ 
    insert(search, insertS);
 }
```

}

here is my Domino class:

```
    public class Domino{
  public int spot1; // the leading half how many spots it has
   public int spot2; //  the trailing half how many spots it has
  public Domino next; // a link to the next Domino (type)?
   public Domino back; // a link to the previous Domino
 private int zero;


 /** 
  * Constructor
  * Creates null Domino
  *
  */
  public Domino(){
    this(0,0 , null, null);
 }
 /** 
  * Constructor
  * a constructor for Domino with given spots
  */
  public Domino( int spot1, int spot2){
    this(spot1,spot2, null, null);  
 }
 /**
  * Constructor
  * @param: all fields
  * setting variables
  */
  public Domino(int spot1, int spot2, Domino next, Domino back){
    this.spot1 = spot1;
    this.spot2 = spot2;
    this.next = next;
   this.back = back;
 }
 /**
  * toString(): prints out single Domino
  *
  */
    public String toString(){
      if(this == null){
        return("[empty]");
     }else{
       return("[ " + spot1 + " | "+ spot2 + "]");
     }

  }



 }
```

I've really been stuck on this for the past day or so and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be great. If you need the client code please say so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of encountering a zero domino, you assign engine to be the current domino. As engine is the head of the list, this is equivalent to deleting all the items preceding the one containing a zero. Deletion in linked list is usually accomplished by something like:

```
toDelete.back.next = toDelete.next;
toDelete.next.back = toDelete.back
```

where toDelete is a Domino object with a zero in this case. As no domino now has a reference to the toDelete domino, it is essentially deleted.